# Vaadin Flow UnsupportedOperationException: Confirmed duplicate message from the client

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin10

I want to use Anchor element with Button as child, but in this case i got exception:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Confirmed duplicate message
>   from the client. Expected sync id: 2, got 1. Message start:
>   {"csrfToken":"992caf41-4b1c-4b1e-97da-04c83c55301a","rpc":[{"type":"event","node":10,"event":"click","data":{"event.shiftKey":false,"event.metaKey":false,"event.detail":1,"event.ctrlKey":false,"event.clientX":693,"event.clientY":166,"event.altKey":false,"event.button":0,"event.screenY":262,"event.screenX":693}}],"syncId":1,"clientId":1}

Here is source code for my elements:

```
Button button = new Button("Rules");
Anchor anchor = new Anchor("/rules", button);
```

My classes sources: https://pastebin.com/G8zU0csP

I am using Vaadin 14.0.5
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add both `button` and `anchor` to the UI? if this is the case, then you should add only `anchor`directly. This seems to work for me without any problems

```java
Button button = new Button("Title");
Anchor anchor = new Anchor("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58684723/vaadin-flow-unsupportedoperationexception-confirmed-duplicate-message-from-the", button); add(anchor);
```

Could you add more details to your example? What is the URL in your Anchor?

Comment: ```
Button button = new Button(title);
Anchor anchor = new Anchor("/rules", button);
```

Comment: The problem is encountered in case of use anchor with links to navigate inside of application

Comment: sure, i add only Anchor to the UI

Comment: I still can't reproduce an error, if I simply navigate to another Route. Do you have a minimum reproducible example? Like only those two views with an error?

Comment: What is an `anchor` element in your `BaseView`? How your `configurePage` looks like? If I simply rename `anchor` to use `logogAnchor` and leave `configurePage` without implementation, then everything works. Which makes me thing that problem is not with the snippet code you are asking about, but the `anchor` you haven't shared. There is not much we could help with, if we can't reproduce a problem. Sorry about that

Comment: after long time of investigation i found that this error occurred only on my laptop in firefox 70.0.1(latest at this time), in google chrome all works correctly, and on another firefox  same version installed on another one laptop everything works perfect too.